# passing parameters to popup form php bootscape

Tags: php, parameters, popup

I have below code with href link that will open the popup form. How can I pass the parameters to this popup form??

```
echo "<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" href=\"#contactAdvertiser\" data-toggle=\"modal\" ><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"></i> Reply </a></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        this is a simple way only
        i make use of bootstrap and jquery
        <br/>
        this are buttons generated by the php
         <br/>
        you can create a element data attribute where in you can put
         <br/>
        your php contents to be transfer to the modal or popup
        <br/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary clickbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" data-transfer="This is a data that i am holding generated by the php">Small modal</button>

        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary clickbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" data-transfer="This is a data that i am holding generated by the php sample 2">Small modal1</button>

        <div id="popup" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <p>Sample Test Data</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // bind on click event on the button once it was open
                // change the contents of modal or the popup
                // contents
                $('.clickbutton').on('click', function() {
                    // get the data-transfer attribute and
                    // send it to modal/popup data
                    var data = $(this).attr('data-transfer');
                    // change the content of the modal using javascript
                    // jquery dom manipulation
                    $('#popup').find('.modal-content p').html(data);
                });

            });

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```